# Is $\sigma$ implied to be a monothonic function of $\epsilon$ in the definition of function limit?

Tags: limits, functions

I am a novice at Math and trying to understand a definition of a limit for a function:

If $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\sigma>0$ such that if from $0 < |x-a| < \sigma$ follows $|f(x)-A| < \epsilon$, this fact is written down as $lim_{x\to a}f(x)=A$ meaning that if $x$ gets infinitely closer to $a$ then $f(x)$ gets infinitely closer to some value $A$, which is considered to be a "limit" of function $f(x)$at the point $a$.

The value of chosen $\sigma$ thus depends on at least the value of $\epsilon$ or also on the value of $a$ if the function is not uniformly continuous. Its choice is thus not arbitrary according to definition.

What I don't see in the definition then, is that $\sigma(\epsilon)$ (considering $a$ fixed) has to be a monotonic function. If it isn't, then we can imagine a case where for decreasing values of $\epsilon$ we could get increasing values of $\sigma$, which would mean that $x$ wouldn't be getting infinitely closer to $a$.

Comment: First, $\sigma$ is not a function of $\epsilon$, only, one knows that for every $\epsilon$, there exists some $\sigma$ such that etc. Second, by pure logic, if some given $\sigma$ fits the condition for some given $\epsilon$ then the same $\sigma$ also fits for every $\epsilon'$ larger than $\epsilon$. In this sense, I guess one could decree that $\sigma$ is nondecreasing with $\epsilon$.

Comment: In symbols: define $$\Sigma(\epsilon)=\sup A(\epsilon)$$ where $$A(\epsilon)=\{\sigma>0\mid\forall x,|x-a|<\sigma\implies|f(x)-A|<\epsilon\}$$ then the function $\Sigma$ is nondecreasing since $\epsilon<\epsilon'$ implies $A(\epsilon)\subseteq A(\epsilon')$.

Comment: @Did And also $\Sigma(\epsilon) \in A(\epsilon)$ for each $\epsilon > 0$, which is also important.

Comment: Note that for limits of functions, we actually assume $0<|x-a| < \sigma$. In other fords, what the function does _at_ $x = a$ (it has some totally different, crazy value, or it's undefined, for instance) is not of relevance. What you wrote is the definition of $f$ being _continuous_ at $a$.

Comment: @Arthur Howcome it is a definition of continuity at point $a$ if I never mentioned that $A = f(a)$?

Comment: If you use just $|x-a| < \sigma$, then you are, among other things, saying that for any $\epsilon>0$, and $x-a = 0$, we have $|f(x)-A|<\epsilon$. That is a very long way of saying $f(a) = A$. Specifying $0<|x-a| < \sigma$ instead is exactly what lets you claim that you never mentioned $A = f(a)$, since that disallows $x = a$.

Comment: I see the mistake, thanks. Possibility of $0 = |x−a|$ could imply the equality of $x$ and $a$ and thus $A = f(a)$ (question edited).

Comment: @Did Could you clarify the statement: "the function $Σ$ is non-decreasing since $\epsilon<\epsilon′$ implies $A(\epsilon)⊆A(\epsilon′)"$. How do you conclude that?

Comment: Which part is not clear? That $u<v$ implies $A(u)\subseteq A(v)$? Or that $B\subseteq C$ implies $\sup B\leqslant \sup C$?

Comment: I meant the part with $u<v$ implies $A(u)⊆A(v)$

Comment: Hmmm... Fix some $u<v$ and some $\sigma$ in $A(u)$, then how could one prove that $\sigma$ is in $A(v)$ as well? By definition of $A(u)$, one knows that ... hence ... (Unrelated: Please use @.)